# How to create a cart with file type modifier option via v3 cart API in BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

Can anyone please help me with how to create a cart with the file type modifier option of a product via V3 Cart API in BigCommerce?
I've already followed the [Cart API Documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/20c2c55c1763f-create-a-cart).
Still, I'm not finding any solution to my issue.

My product in store-front looks like the below image.

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked that BigCommerce doesn't allow to create a cart with file type modifier via v3 Carts API.

Answer (score 0):

Hello have you tried updating the parameters for your product modifier in you storefront for the product to only accept the file types you currently want? I.E. Product > View > Customizations > Modifier Options. If you are looking for modifier options API it would be in the Product API Documentation under Modifiers [located here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/b53222c895907-create-a-product-modifier).